# Type Mismatch error in Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am running this macro in Excel 2010 over a value of text in Column A. The error message is "Type Mismatch". Is it a coding issue or is it related to Excel 2010? Since the same works well in Excel 2003.

The macro identifies common strings and provides an output with words and counts.

```
Sub Common_words()
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim lLoop As Long
    Dim rCell As Range

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each rCell In Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
            vArray = Split(rCell.Value, " ")
            For lLoop = LBound(vArray) To UBound(vArray)
                If Not .exists(vArray(lLoop)) Then
                    .Add vArray(lLoop), 1
                Else
                    .Item(vArray(lLoop)) = .Item(vArray(lLoop)) + 1
                End If
            Next lLoop
        Next rCell
        Range("B1").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.keys)
        Range("C1").Resize(.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(.items)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: I don't think that will solve the issue. Like other objects, Microsoft Scripting Runtime works using late bind.